# Why use child_process instead of cluster in Node?

Tags: node.js, debugging

As far as I can tell, the `cluster` module is just an enhancement of the `child_process` module in that it allows TCP port sharing between forked processes.  However, it does have the "debug port shuffle" functionality built in so that you don't have to write extra code to do debugging when you fork worker processes, whereas `child_process` doesn't have that.

So is there any reason why you would use `child_process` instead?  Can I just use `cluster` for the easier debugging even though I don't need its port sharing functionality, or will there be negative side-effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: `cluster` and `child_process` do different things; for example, when you start a new process with `cluster` it always forks and starts from the module where the current code started, whereas with `child_process` you can specify which new module to run.  There does seem to be a ton of overlapping functionality though, so it's odd that there are two separate modules IMHO.